# One function access different controllers angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have to angular js files as a different controllers. one controller is user controller. other is customer controller. i need to access user controller function inside the customer controller. please check my sample code

user controller (user.js)

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('user', function($scope) {
$scope.totalAmount = function(){
$scope.total = $scope.perAmount * $scope.month;
}
});
```

customer controller (customer.js)

```
app.controller('customer', function($scope) {
$scope.customerTotalAmount = $scope.total;
});
```

how i do it,can you help me. both controllers are in different js files. how i share this function inside the my application

Comment: Use a `service`

Comment: i tried w3school example , but not working,,

Comment: Post here whatever you tried that didn't work